# Apache: URLs with HTTPS not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, http-status-code-404

Every request on my site is redirected to a specific PHP file (handle.php). This works fine for HTTP requests, but not when I force HTTPS in the URL.

**This works (HTTP):** http://my.domain.com/myrequest

**This works (HTTPS):** https://my.domain.com/handle.php **(every request to a specific file works fine in HTTPS)**

**This doesn't works (HTTPS):** https://my.domain.com/myrequest **(404 Not Found)**

In short, there is a problem when i force HTTPS and I try to make a request that needs to be redirected to handle.php.

At first I thought that HTTPS requests were not allowed, but as you can see when you request a specific file it works fine, so I think there is a problem with the redirect.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ handle.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**VirtualHost Config**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin
        ServerName my.domain.com
        ServerAlias my.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /data/www/my.domain.com/docroot/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /data/www/my.domain.com/docroot/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options ExecCGI MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /data/www/my.domain.com/logs/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /data/www/my.domain.com/logs/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName my.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /data/www/my.domain.com/docroot/
        SSLEngine on
        CustomLog /data/www/my.domain.com/logs/ssl-access.log combined
        ErrorLog /data/www/my.domain.com/logs/ssl-error.log
        SSLCertificateFile /data/www/my.domain.com/certs/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /data/www/my.domain.com/certs/cert.key
        <Directory /data/www/my.domain.com/docroot/>
                Require all granted
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you show us VirtualHost configuration?

Comment: I just added it in the description. Thank you!

Comment: You have `AllowOverride None` in your `:443` VirtualHost, that prevents `.htaccess` from being applied

Comment: also, [you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when)

Comment: Thank you, now it works!